# Not sure how to proceed: If $f: B \cup C \rightarrow A$ is a function, then $f = f_{[B]} \cup f_{[C]}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

I'm using Charles Pinter's *A Book of Set Theory* and I'm given the following theorem to prove.

***Theorem 2.15***: If $f: B \cup C \rightarrow A$ is a function, then $f = f_{[B]} \cup f_{[C]}$

The book states that the proof is simple, so I think that I'm missing something fundamental. Right now I think my best bet to prove this is to work with the conditions for a function (listed below). But I'm not too sure how to proceed, as I haven't seen a similar proof to imitate. I'm particularly confused about where exactly I should break up the function $f$ into the union of $f_{[B]}$ and $f_{[C]}$, respectively.

Could anyone point out what I may be missing in the proof, or some other guidance?

---

We defined a function as follows:
Let $A$ and $B$ be classes and let $f$ be a graph.
Then $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a function iff

1. $\forall x \in A$, $\exists y \in B$ such that $(x,y) \in f$, and the image of $x$ is unique.
2. domain $f = A$, and
3. range $f \subseteq B$.

*Attempted Proof/Outline*

Assume that $f: B \cup C \rightarrow A$ is a function. Now,

**(1)** $x \in$ dom $f$  $\Rightarrow$ $\exists y \ni$ $(x,y) \in f$

**(2)** $\Rightarrow$ $(x,y) \in (B \cup C) \times A$

**(3)** $\Rightarrow$ $x \in (B \cup C)$ $\wedge$ $y \in A$

**(4)** $\Rightarrow$ ($x \in B$ $\vee$ $x \in C$) $\wedge$ $y \in A$

**(5)** After distributing $\Rightarrow$ ($x \in B \wedge y \in A$) $\vee$ ($x \in C \wedge y \in A$)

**(6)** Returning to Cartesian Product $\Rightarrow$ $(x,y) \in [(B \times A) \cup (C \times A)]$

---

Right here it looks like I have the function split into a union, which I want, since we defined a function to simply be a graph. The next step would be showing the converse, namely, $A \subseteq$ dom $f$. If the above is correct, I have a general idea how to proceed.

Comment: You seem to have gotten confused about domain and range of a function.  The input values for $f $ are the elements of $B\cup C $, so that is the domain of $f $, and $A $ is the range (or codomain).

Comment: Do you have a definition of the notation $f_{[B]}$? If so, you will need to use it somewhere. If not, you cannot possibly hope to prove a theorem that depends on the meaning of that notation.

Answer (score 1):

You're heading in the wrong direction, I'm afraid. Your approach will help you show that $\operatorname{dom} f=(\operatorname{dom} f_{[B]})\cup(\operatorname{dom} f_{[C]}),$ but that isn't what you're trying to show. Instead, you wish to show two facts: $$f\subseteq f_{[B]}\cup f_{[C]}$$ and $$f\supseteq f_{[B]}\cup f_{[C]}.$$

On the one hand, take any $\langle x,y\rangle\in f.$ Clearly, $$x\in\operatorname{dom} f=B\cup C=(\operatorname{dom} f_{[B]})\cup(\operatorname{dom} f_{[C]}),$$ so what can you conclude by definition of restriction?

The reverse inclusion is similar.

Comment: By definition of restriction do you mean $f|_{A}:f \cap (A \times$ range $f)$?

Comment: Well, *I* might use that notation, yes, but I was interpreting $f_{[B]}$ (for example) to denote the restriction of $f$ to to $B$. Is this what it means, or does it mean something else entirely?

Comment: Ah, now I see. I missed a definition in my book for a restriction of a function. I'll re-asses the problem tomorrow and see if I can prove it.

Answer (score 1):

First your definition need be changed to:

$f: A \rightarrow B$ is a function iff

1. $\forall x \in A$, $\exists y \in B,\:y$ is unique such that $(x,y) \in f$.
2. $\mathcal{D}(f) = A$, and
3. $\mathcal{R}(f)\subseteq B$.

where $\mathcal{D}(f)$ is the domain of $f$, and $\mathcal{R}(f)$ the range of $f$.

Denote $f|_B^A=f: B \rightarrow A$ as $f$ under domain $B$ and range $A$. Then 
$$
f|_B^A=f\cap (B\times A)
$$
where $A\subset \mathcal{R}(f)$, the range of $f$.

Next 
\begin{align}
f|_{B\cup C}^A&=f\cap (B\cup C\times A)
\\
&=f\cap (B\times A\cup C\times A)
\\
&=(f\cap (B\times A))\cup (f\cap (C\times A))
\\
&=f|_{B}^A\cup f|_{C}^A
\end{align}